# Slow upload speeds when using gcloud compute scp and gsutil cp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-storage

I tried uploading a single file from a local drive directly to a google cloud compute vm instance using `gcloud compute scp` and to a google bucket using `gsutil cp` but in both cases the transfer speeds were significantly slower than my internet speed (by 10-100x). If I upload using the gui in the ssh from the browser window, it's also slow. However, manually uploading to other sites seems to be fine (I tried Box and gmail). This problem appears to be isolated to this particular desktop computer, which admittedly is somewhat old (maybe 8 years old, running Windows 7). In particular, I tried unplugging the ethernet cable from this computer and plugging it in to my laptop (Windows 10) and had no speed issues. There were also no speed issues with my laptop on WiFi, or with another desktop (Ubuntu 16.04) with a wired internet connection.

So clearly, something is wrong with this old computer, which unfortunately I'm constrained to use. Is there any reason to believe that gcloud tools operate more slowly on Windows 7? I have virtually no experience with network diagnostics, so I don't have many ideas for where to begin diagnosing this problem. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
I tried using scp with WinSCP and sftp with FileZilla and the upload speeds were fine ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try running gsutil perfdiag. It runs several transfers against GCS buckets and measures performance metrics (latency, overall throughput, system resource information, etc.). From looking at the report it generates, it might become more evident where the bottleneck(s) are. You could also try running it on a machine that doesn't have the performance problem, and comparing the two reports to try to see what looks significantly worse on the machine with the performance problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I just did this comparison using the default settings, except setting -n to 20. For latency, it seems all numbers are comparable except for the 1-MB upload, for which the problematic computer is ~2.5x slower. For write throughput, the problematic computer is also ~2.5x slower. For read throughput, they're about the same. This just further confirms that this machine is problematic, but I'm still not sure where to go from here. Is there more information I can get out of the perdiag report?

Comment: Take a look at details in the report about meminfo (is there little free memory, which could cause thrashing), tempdir (are you writing temp files to a slow partition, like an NFS mount), tcp_retransmit (is the slow machine seeing a much higher rate of TCP retransmissions), load_avg (is your CPU overloaded)?